# Динамическая подгрузка модулей

Tags: php

Вообщем есть 4 сервиса, у каждого сервиса свое ядро свой конфиг свое пространство имен и есть апи который принимает запрос и проверяет состояние по каждому сервису и выдает результат. Проблема в следующем, как можно реализовать функционал так чтобы не грузить ядро для каждого сервиса. При проверке состояние мне получается надо заинклудить 4 ядра как по мне это не оч хорошо. Как можно обойти данную проблему?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то почитайте про "Балансировка нагрузки" к примеру (https://www.webmascon.com/topics/technologies/4c.asp)

Comment: Не совсем то,тут проблема не в нагрузке, а в том что приходится иклюдить 4.Я уже думал это отдельным процессом делать, и в нем уже под каждый сервис ядро подгружать, и так для каждого сервиса будет процесс